# Adding Qxt plugin to Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer, libqxt

I'm having a problem with adding the Qxt library to Qt Designer. The error it gives is:

Cannot load library C:/Qt/4.6.2/plugins/designer/QxtDesignerPlugins.dll; The specified module cannot be found.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` environment variable to `1` and then try again.  This should give you some additional debug output that will help isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you check that this file is actually there?
2. Usually, the problem with designer plugins is that they're installed in the wrong directory, or linked against a different Qt (esp. debug vs. release).

Comment: File is there... tried to put the dlls and other files in many different directories before giving up.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the plugin itself can find all the dlls it depends on. Use depends.exe (Dependency Checker) or maybe FileMon.exe to find out.

The error message can be a bit misleading, as it is the same if any of the primary dlls dependencies are missing too.